# What is the probability that King selected the first box under the condition that the ball he selected is white?

Tags: probability

*There are two boxes; the first one contains 10 white balls and 5 black balls; the other one contains 10 black balls and 5 white balls. King randomly selects a box (with equal probabilities) and then randomly takes a ball from this box (with equal probabilities). What is the probability that King selected the first box under the condition that the ball he selected is white?*

So my approach is I thought that I should calculate the probability of the first box then the probability of the second and just add them but that's been wrong so can someone help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know Bayes' Theorem?

Comment: Actually struggling with it, but I also thought about since they are with equal probabilities, I would just calculate the probability of the white balls in the first box but that didn't work either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

F = First Box, S = Second Box, W = White Balls, B = Black Balls

$$P(F|W)=\frac {P(F\cap W)}{P(W)}=\frac {P(F)\times P(W|F)}{P(F)\times P(W|F)+P(S)\times P(W|S)}=\frac {\frac 12 \times \frac 23}{\frac 12 \times \frac 23 + \frac 12 \times \frac 13}=\frac 23$$

[image: Tree Diagram]